# Unlink File path error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

got an issue with a path to a file I need to delete via user input. I basically had it working on local host but not on my live server (with the unlink php method). Its getting an error now saying it cannot delete file because of the path i think.

My question is this should the path be a "creativetree.co/creativetreeBeta/uploaded_files/imgfile.jpg"

Does this need to be inserted to get the path to work? Heres some of my code (plenty more but this is the most relevant).

```
if(isset($_POST["filetodelete"])){
$deletefileid = $_POST['filetodelete'];
$projid = $_POST['projid'];

$get_files_to_unlink = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE files_id = $deletefileid";                    
$get_unlink_result=mysql_query($get_files_to_unlink);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_unlink_result)){
    $filetounlink = $row['fileurl'];//uploaded_files/imgname.jpg
}

//url problem here worked on localhost not when live
unlink($filetounlink);

$sql_remove_file="DELETE FROM files WHERE files_id = $deletefileid";
$result_file=mysql_query($sql_remove_file);
}
```

Comment: include the exact error message

Comment: Check out for the file permission may be it is creating the issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to unlink a file using the URI path, you will receive this warning:

```
unlink() [function.unlink]: HTTP does not allow unlinking
```

It should still work, and you can suppress the warning using `@` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, you need to use a document relative path or root relative path such as:

```
./uploaded_files/somefile.jpg
```

or

```
/var/www/mysite/uploaded_files/somefile.jpg
```

Most likely though, the issue is with folder permissions. PHP probably only has read rights to that folder.

As mentioned in other comments, taking values from $_POST and entering straight into your query leaves you wide open for SQL Injection. You should look into parameterized queries using PDO instead.

Answer (score -1):

The path needs to be absolute e.g. /var/www/file/to/delete.pdf
You have to be very carefull with user input!!!

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be absolute.